# Can I solve DDEs starting from an ODE system?

Tags: matlab, ode, dde

I have a system of 4 equations and 5 parameters, I would like to include a time delay on the ODE system but I think is better if I solve a DDE system starting from the ODE system I have already.
Is there a way to connect these two systems in MATLAB?

I tried with this syntax:

```
[t, y] = dde23('ODEfinal', [0 12000], [4*C 0 0 0]);
```

But MATLAB marks error each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your syntax is not correct. This should look like this:

`[t,y] = dde23(@function, <lags>, @history, <tspan>)`, where

`@function` is your ODE function handle
`<lags>` is an array of constants specifying the delay for each variable in your function
`@history` is a function that returns a solution for the system at `t<=t0`, specified in one of these ways:

- A function of `t` such that `y = history(t)` returns the solution `y(t)`
  for `t ≤ t0` as a column vector
- A constant column vector, if `y(t)` is constant
- The solution sol from a previous integration, if this call
  continues that integration
  `<tspan>` specifies `t0` and `tend` for your solution.

Check out the [Matlab page](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dde23.html) on using the dde solvers. Also, typing `edit ddex1` within Matlab will show you an example of using the solver and the auxiliary functions.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks